# Generating function for cardinality of Bruhat intervals

Tags: representation-theory, coxeter-groups, bruhat-tits-theory

For a finite Coxeter system $(W, S)$, the *Poincare polynomial* counts the number of elements of a certain length:
$$ P_W(t) = \sum_{x \in W} t^{l(x)}. $$
The polynomials for types $A$, $B$, and $D$ are relatively simple to write down, for example we have in type $A_n$ that
$$ P_W(t) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n}(1 + t + t^2 + \cdots + t^i). $$
For two elements $x, y \in W$ such that $x \leq y$ in the Bruhat order, let $[x, y]$ denote the interval $\{z \in W \mid x \leq z \leq y\}$. I am most interested in the intervals $[e, x]$ from the identity up to some $x \in W$. Let $Q_W(t)$ be the generating function for the cardinality of these intervals:
$$ Q_W(t) := \sum_{x \in W} t^{\#[\operatorname{id}, x]}.$$
**Question:** Is there a closed form for the polynomials $Q_W(t)$, at least in finite types $A$, $B$, $D$?

Comment: Is $\# [id,x] \neq l(x)+1$ ?

Comment: @ArB For the longest element, $\#[id, w_0] = \#W$.

Comment: can you please explain why? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @ArB there is a very nice geometric explanation but I can't fit that in a comment. In short, in Bruhat order $y\le x$ if there is some reduced word for $x$ which contains a reduced word for $y$ as a sub-word. If $x$ had a unique reduced expression, and we only considered sub-words which are initial segments of $x$ then $\#[id,x]=l(x)+1$, however in reality $x$ will have many reduced expressions, and we can consider any sub-words, which means $[id,x]$ will be much bigger in general. Complicating matters is the fact that many of the sub-words will represent the same elements $y\le x$.

Comment: @Joppy I have spent a lot of time thinking about the polynomials $P_w(t)=\sum_{u\in[id, w]}t^{l(u)}$ for some $w\in W$ which are related to the polynomials you mention. In particular if $w_0$ is the longest element in $W$ then $P_W(t)=P_{w_0}(t)$; and also $\#[id,w]=P_w(1)$ so one could rewrite $Q_W(t)=\sum_{w\in W}t^{P_w(1)}$. However I don't know immediately how to apply that to answer your question. I'd be interested to knot in what context you are interested in these $Q$ polynomials?

Comment: @DavidSheard Thanks for the comments David. I was interested in the $Q$ polynomial from the perspective of the running times of various algorithms (calculating Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials for instance). Although now I realise I want a related polynomial, something like $\sum_{x \in W} \sum_{y \leq x} t^{l(x) - l(y)}$.